# Concat images in OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, histogram, concatenation, mat

I'm trying to concatenate many images in a grid inside a unique image. I have a vector where I collect 400 images(each image is an histogram). What I want to do, is concatenate all of the 400 histograms into a unique final histogram.

How can I solve this?

Comment: in a row? in a grid?

Answer (score 3):

Once you set the dimension of your grid, you just need to find out where each image should be copied inside the grid. Then using `copyTo` in the correct position will produce the desired output.

Have a look at the code. The comment should clarify each step. Let me know it works for you.

```cc
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Define the size of your images
    Size sz(20,20);

    // Create some random images (will be your histograms)
    vector<Mat3b> images(400);
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i)
    {
        Vec3b color(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255);
        images[i] = Mat3b(sz, color);
    }

    //////////////////
    // Create Grid
    //////////////////

    // Define number of columns in the grid
    int n_cols = 20;
    // Define correct number of rows, according to columns
    int n_rows = (images.size() / n_cols) + ((images.size() % n_cols) ? 1 : 0);

    // Create a black image with correct size
    Mat3b grid(n_rows * sz.height, n_cols * sz.width, Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // For each image
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Get x,y position in the grid
        int x = (i % n_cols) * sz.width;
        int y = (i / n_cols) * sz.height;

        // Select the roi in the grid
        Rect roi(x,y,sz.width,sz.height);

        // Copy the image into the roi
        images[i].copyTo(grid(roi));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Possible output:

[image]